Why doesn't array_diff() work straight away with an array of enums, whereas in_array() or array_udiff() do?
Using PHP 8.4, given the following functions:
function test_array_diff($all, $filtered)
{
    return array_diff($all, $filtered);
}

function test_array_udiff($all, $filtered)
{
    return array_udiff($all, $filtered, fn($item1, $item2) => $item1 != $item2);
}

function test_in_array($all, $filtered)
{
    $diff = [];

    foreach ($all as $case) {
        if (!in_array($case, $filtered, true)) {
            $diff[] = $case;
        }
    }

    return $diff;
}

The following enum:
enum MyEnum
{
    case FOO;
    case BAR;
}

And those variables:
$all = MyEnum::cases();
$filtered = [MyEnum::BAR];

Why do subsequent calls work as expected:
var_dump(test_array_udiff($all, $filtered));
var_dump(test_in_array($all, $filtered));

But this one throws:
var_dump(test_array_diff($all, $filtered));


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class MyEnum could not be converted to string

Shouldn't array_diff() be able to work "out of the box" with enum arrays in the same way as in_array() or array_udiff()?

Why is array_udiff returning common elements? and Why does PHP array_udiff return a different result set depending on whether the callback function returns 1 vs -1? and array_udiff seems not work and Understanding array_udiff() and About array_udiff,I want to ask again

Github thread: Enum could not be converted to string with \array_intersect and from PHP internals/externals thread: RFC idea: array_*(Enum)

php array_diff not working with collection of value objects and array_diff() failing while filtering object arrays

A significant note: in_array() with a true third parameter will make type-strict checks.  The spaceship operator does type juggling.  array_diff() also makes (loose) string comparisons.

From the documentation of array_diff():

Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. That is, when the string representation is the same.

Since enums can't be converted to strings, this test is not possible.
The equivalent test_udiff() would be:
function test_array_udiff($all, $filtered)
{
    return array_udiff($all, $filtered, fn($item1, $item2) => (string)$item1 <=> (string)$item2);
}

Note also that you should use the <=> comparison operator. The callback for array_udiff should return a negative, positive, or zero value to indicate the relationship between the values, not a boolean.

My bad, I didn't read the examples... But I think the clarification on string comparison that explains how the function works should be in the Description paragraph, or better an Caution insert in the Parameters paragraph, but not in the Examples paragraph. Examples should remain what they are.

It's the same comparison that most of the other array functions use, and some of them put this information higher up. E.g. array_intersect() and array_unique()

Although my implementation using array_udiff() was bad (it only works for a subset of cases), using array_udiff() to filter elements is a bad idea anyway because of the underlying sorting algorithms applied to the arrays.
Nevertheless, I like the RFC's idea, highlighted by @mickmackusa, of being able to use certain array operations on enumeration arrays.
The implementation below using array_udiff() with the spaceship operator and the enumeration name works now correctly, but is nevertheless very slow with large arrays.
array_udiff($all, $filtered, fn($item1, $item2) => $item1->name <=> $item2->name) ;

I performed performance tests with the following functions using a hundred-value enumeration class:

foreach and in_array()
array_reduce() and in_array()
array_filter() and in_array()
array_walk() and in_array()
array_udiff()

On my hardware with PHP 8.4, using the foreach loop in conjunction with the in_array() function gives the fastest results, while using the array_reduce() and array_filter() functions instead is about ~20% slower, the array_walk() function is about ~30% slower, and using the array_udiff() function is by far much slower, by over 380%.
array_reduce($all, function ($carry, $case) use ($filtered) {
    if (!in_array($case, $filtered, true)) {
        $carry[] = $case;
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);

array_filter($all, fn($case) => !in_array($case, $filtered, true));

$diff = [];
array_walk($all, function ($value) use ($filtered, &$diff) {
    if (!in_array($value, $filtered, true)) {
        $diff[] = $value;
    }
}, $diff);


It would be helpful to know the size of your payloads when you were performance testing.
